# trying to generate bar chart in d3 using object-oriented approach

Tags: javascript, d3.js

plotI'm new to d3 and fairly new to javascript as well (most of my experience is with python). I recently went trough a tutorial in the book *Interactive Data Visualization: for the web* by Scott Murray on creating a bar chart. I didn't have nay issues with completing the tutorial, but the approach he takes in the book seems to be mostly procedural using global variables. I would like to create a similar chart, but use an object-oriented approach to be able to encapsulate the variables and reuse the code to generate multiple charts in one script without having to repeat the code over and over again. This is what I've tried so far without any luck:

```
        function d3Chart(id, data, width, height, padding) {
            this.id = id
            this.data = data
            this.width = width
            this.height = height
            this.padding = padding
            this.svg =  d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
                .attr("class", "chart")
                .attr("id". this.id);
            this.yscale = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
                .range([h - padding, padding])
            this.xscale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .domain(d3.range(data.length))
                .rangeRoundBands([padding,w-padding], 0.05)
        };

        d3Chart.prototype.rect = function() {

            this.rect = this.svg.selectAll("rect")
                .data(this.data)
                .enter()
                .append("rect");
        }

        d3Chart.prototype.plot = function() {

             this.rect.attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return this.xscale(i);
                })
                .attr("y", function (d) {
                    return this.yscale(d);
                })
                .attr("width", this.xscale.rangeBand())
                .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return this.height - this.padding - this.yscale(d);
                })
                .attr("fill", function(d) {
                    return "rgb(" + (100 - d) + ", 0, " + (d*10) + ")";
                });
            }

        var chart = new d3Chart("chart1", [5, 15, 10, 30, 20, 45, 15, 10, 5], 600, 400, 40);
        chart.rect()
        chart.plot()
```

I'm sure there's something pretty simple I'm doing wrong, does anyone know why this isn't working, or if this is even the right approach to take? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Dmitry Soshnikov wrote a very [short but sweet description](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core/) of the mechanics of Javascript which is worth reading. Most of you OOP needs probably can be solved by returning a function within a function that has the variables set and captured in a closure, encapsulation. If you need to extend base object have a look a the [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) and Object.defineProperty methods.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem with your code is that you have a couple of typos in there, e.g. `.` instead of `,` and `h` instead of `height`. The second problem is that you're making everything an attribute of `this`, which will be different in different contexts. For example, in

```
this.rect.attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return this.xscale(i);
            })
```

the two `this` refer to different objects -- in the second case `this` is the actual DOM element you're operating on and does not have the attribute you're referring to.

So you need to save everything to attributes of a global object, like `window`. This is of course not much better than using global variables. For a more object-oriented approach, you would need to create an object that contains all the information and pass that around, or implement methods that you can call on it.

I've put your fixed code in a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9Lvk5/).

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. As I said, I'm new to javascript so i'm still having a tough time wrapping my mind around the "this" keyword.

Comment: whay you say "For a more object-oriented approach, you would need to create an object that contains all the information and pass that around, or implement methods that you can call on it." do you have a more specific example of this. could i bind the variables to an svg element rather than "window"?

Comment: What I'm saying is that you would create a custom object (that is, simply a generic object) to use for the attributes. Binding the variables to an SVG element isn't a good idea.

Comment: Is there any chance you could show me a quick example of what you mean. I haven't been able to get it to work without setting variables to "window"

Comment: [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) is a primer on objects in Javascript. You would create this at the beginning of your code and pass it to every method that you call so that the method gets access to its attributes.